# Xpath for extracting attibute values in any arbitrary XML schema

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to write an integration engine where I get SOAP XMLs which basically contains db query values which I have to extract from the XML and formulate fast SQL queries.

The issue is the input XMLs are from various sources and have arbitrary schemas. The only common pattern is that I have two types of nodes to extract values from. These contain simple types and complex types. For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<for1:submittedData xmlns:for1="http://www.example.com/abc/1.1/">
    <td conceptName="PostalAddress_StreetNumber" name="postal.streetNumber"/>
    <td conceptName="PostalAddress_StreetName" name="postal.streetAddress"/>
    <Reports conceptName="LaboratoryReport" minDateTime="2012-09-16T00:00:00.000" maxDateTime="2015-09-02T23:59:59.999" searchString="Loinc Test" order="dateDescend" name="clinical.diagnosticReport">
        <SendingFacility conceptName="Report_SendingFacility" name="sendingFacility"/>
        <Report_Subject conceptName="Report_Subject" name="name"/>
    </Reports>
</for1:submittedData>
```

I want to extract all the attribute values of the simple types such as PostalAddress_StreetNumber, postal.streetNumber, PostalAddress_StreetName, postal.streetAddress in one Xpath query and then all the complex types LaboratoryReport, 2012-09-16T00:00:00.000. For the complex types, the rule to identify is if an element has conceptName and hasChildNodes='true' then treat it as a  complex type. 
Another example of input example on which the same Xpath has to work is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form:submittedData xmlns:form="http://www.example.com/abc1/1.1/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>PostalAddress_StreetNumber</th>
                    <th>PostalAddress_StreetName</th>
                </tr>
                <td conceptName="PostalAddress_StreetNumber" name="postal.streetNumber"/>
                <td conceptName="PostalAddress_StreetName" name="postal.streetAddress"/>
                <tr conceptName="LaboratoryReport" minDateTime="2012-09-16T00:00:00.000" maxDateTime="2015-09-02T23:59:59.999" searchString="Loinc Test Results Ful" order="dateDescend" name="clinical.diagnosticReport">
                    <td conceptName="Report_SendingFacility" name="sendingFacility"/>
                    <td conceptName="Report_Subject" name="name"/>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</form:submittedData>
```

I tried extracting all the conceptNames as `//@conceptName`. But I don't know how to formulate those rules in the Xpath queries. Can someone help?

Comment: So you want to get *all* attributes from simple types, I think this part is clear. Then what do you want to get from complex types, all attributes too? I don't think so. So what do you want to extract form complex types?

Comment: Yes, all attributes from both the simple and complex types in two separate xpath queries. From the complex types I want to extract the attribute values as well. for example maxDateTime and maxDateTime values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all attributes from complex types you can use the following XPath :

```
//*[@* and *]//@*
```

**brief explanation :**

- `//*[@* and *]` : find all elements having child element(s) and attribute(s)...
- `//@*` : ...then from each of such element and it's descendant elements, return all the attributes

And use the following to get all attributes from simple types :

```
//*[not(*)][not(parent::*[@* and *])]/@*
```

**brief explanation :**

- `//*[not(*)]` : find all elements that doesn't have child element...
- `[not(parent::*[@* and *])]` : ...and doesn't have parent element matching complex type criteria...
- `/@*` : ...then from each of such element, return all the attributes

Comment: //@*[parent::*[not(*)]] also returns the complex types

Comment: Not sure, that didn't happen to me. I tested using both of your XML sample here : http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Comment: Should only get Attribute='conceptName="PostalAddress_StreetNumber"'
Attribute='name="postal.streetNumber"'
Attribute='conceptName="PostalAddress_StreetName"'
Attribute='name="postal.streetAddress"' but I get Attribute='conceptName="PostalAddress_StreetNumber"'
Attribute='name="postal.streetNumber"'
Attribute='conceptName="PostalAddress_StreetName"'
Attribute='name="postal.streetAddress"'
Attribute='conceptName="Report_SendingFacility"'
Attribute='name="sendingFacility"'
Attribute='conceptName="Report_Subject"'
Attribute='name="name"'

Comment: @iceman hmm.. do you mean that child of complex type (children of `<tr conceptName="LaboratoryReport"` for example) is considered part of the parent complex type, not individual simple types? And those children shouldn't be returned by XPath for simple types, right?

Comment: @iceman check the updated answer. That should work fine, if I understood the requirement correctly